# in Scala: not able to fin a class in Linux but in Windows for forName

Tags: linux, windows, scala

I am writing Scala code. In windows it is working:

```
Class.forName("opt/user/Foo")
```

where Foo is a Scala class. However, in Ubuntu Linux this is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look suspiciously like common directory names.

Probably your Linux class path includes a directory like `opt` or `user` that is taken as a package name.